# Serving static files via koa and using basic auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, koa

I've build a small test-server using Koa. It is supposed to serve all files living in the same directory (and sub-directories) but requiring to authenticate with basic auth. Therefore I'm using the packages [koa-static](https://github.com/koajs/static) & [koa-basic auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-basic-auth)

I couldn't figure out how to combine both middlewares? 
When using: `app.use(function *() { });` a `this.body = 'text'` is expected instead of using `koa-static`.

This is the complete code:

```
"use strict";

var koa   = require('koa')
  , serve = require('koa-static')
  , auth  = require('koa-basic-auth');

var app = koa();

// Default configuration
let port = 3000;

app.use(function *(next){
    try {
      yield next;
    } catch (err) {
      if (401 == err.status) {
        this.status = 401;
        this.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
        this.body = 'Access denied';
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  });


// Require auth
app.use(auth({ name: 'admin' , pass: 'admin'}))

//Serve static files
//DOESN'T WORK
app.use(function *() {
  serve('.')
});

// WORKS
app.use(function *(){
  this.body = 'secret';
});

app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you must have `yield` to make a wrapper of a middleware:**

```
app.use(function *() {
  yield serve('.')
});
```

**or directly use the middleware without the wrapper function:**

```
app.use(serve('.'));
```